# reading from disk multiple times possibly cause bottleneck

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find out where the bottleneck of a ruby script is. I suspect that it might happen because the script parses thousands of lines and, for each one, it checks if a certain file is present in disk and eventually reads its contents.

```
def sectionsearch(brand, season, video)
  mytab.trs.each_with_index do |row, i|

    # ...some code goes here...
    f = "modeldesc/" + brand.downcase + "/" + modelcode + ".html"                  
    if File.exist?(f)
      modeldesc = File.read(f)                                                     
    else                                                                           
      modeldesc = ""                                                               
    end 
    # ...more code here...

  end 
end
```

Given that there are no more than 30 different "modelcode" files for thousands of record, I was looking for a different approach that reads all the content of the folder before the each loop (since it is not going to change during the execution).

Is this approach going to speed up my script, also is this the right way to implement this?

Comment: Well you can look at using something like ruby-prof to profile the script, but generally speaking if you are hitting the Disk everytime to check if a file exists it could act as a bottleneck.  You could read the entire directory and store all files, and then just look them up.  Another option would be to cache the lookups.  So the you take the disk hit on the first lookup and then subsequent lookups will be faster. And you don't need to iterate all brands/models up front.

Comment: @Doon, it looks like a good idea. Would you have a new object for each file or store all the files in a single hash like {:model_foo => "<html>...</html>"; :model_bar => "<html>......</html>" } ?

Comment: How big are the model files? What's their average size, and/or, what's the maximum size?

Comment: @theTinMan just a few lines each, very small indeed

Comment: Hmm. If they're that small, how many do you think the maximum number will be that you'll need to load at a time? This could be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: premature optimization or not, caching the file.exist? and the read should save a bunch of IO.  But it all depends on how many times this routine is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like a hash (passing a block) to check for the file, on unknown keys:

```
def sectionsearch(brand, season, video)

   modeldescrs = Hash.new do |cache, model|
      if File.exist?(model)
        cache[model] = File.read(model)
      else
        cache[model] = ''
      end
    end

  mytab.trs.each_with_index do |row, i|

    # ...some code goes here...
    f = "modeldesc/" + brand.downcase + "/" + modelcode + ".html"                  
     puts modeldescrs[f]
    # ...more code here...

  end 
end
```

then just access `modeldescrs[f]` when you need it (the puts above is an example)  if the key doesn't exist the block will be executed and it will look it up / populate it.   see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html  for more info on the block form of the initializer for `Hash`

Also you could make modeldescrs an instance variable if it needs to be saved.